# Why doesn't the CIA contact, whom Bryan Mills (Liam Neeson) asked for help, know Albanian?

Tags: plot-explanation, taken

In *Taken* (2008), Bryan Mills' (Liam Neeson) CIA contact knows, from hearing the kidnappers' voices, exactly which village in Albania they're from. But apparently he doesn't know Albanian because Bryan has to hire a translator in Paris to translate what the kidnappers said.

How could the CIA agent know Albanian so well that he can tell which village they're from but doesn't know a word of Albanian?

Comment: Isn't the CIA agent just someone on the phone back home, *before* he goes to Paris? He needs someone on the ground right then and there

Answer (score 30):

The CIA contact is just passing on the results of the analysis of the recording made by Neeson's character.

He's at the end of a phone line..

> Sam, it's me. I need a favor. I'm gonna download something. I need it analyzed. Right now.

Sam replies...

> They're speaking Albanian. Based on their accents and dialects, they must be from Tropoja.

But when Mills needs someone **local** who can speak Albanian he hires the translator.

Comment: So in other words the CIA contact might not be the one who identified the village; he just passed the recording to the CIA's analysis team, then forwarded the result to Neeson's character.

Comment: Yep, absolutely.